# <aura:html tag="style"> not working after summer 19 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I applied the below code to increase the width of quickAction lightning component

```
<aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container { 
        width : 60% !important; max-width : 80% !important; 
    } 
</aura:html>
```

But after summer 19 it is not working and not getting applied. Any changes has occured in Summer19.

Comment: That never should have worked to begin with. I'm not surprised it's not working now.

Comment: It was working correctly till yesterday. Today slds-modal_container not working

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't be trying to override the standard UI.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox.. is there any particular reason that it shouldn't have worked

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox.. I was trying to increase the width of lightning component which is used in quick action.

Comment: One of the features intended by Lightning was to present a consistent user interface. Being able to override the LEX UI is antithetical to that design goal. You should **not** try to change the UI, but instead make your components reactive to use the available space.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox.. is there any way to increase the width of the component..I m using lighting:layout and lighting:layout item..I m not using any HTML tags

Comment: Nope. You're asking the wrong question, really. You should be asking something like "how can I make my component fit in the available space?" Keep in mind that if you're trying to make your component wider, it won't fit on mobile devices, etc. You need a reactive design.

Comment: Can u redirect me to any sample example. I using the component from quick action

Comment: It'd probably be better if you just ask your question and include the code so we can help you out. There are a *lot* of examples on the Internet, but without knowing what you're trying to do, it's hard to give you a specific example that would help you.

Answer (score 2):

First, in Aura, we support styling using a component CSS file to ensure styles are scoped with .THIS and don't bleed and create problems with Salesforce and third-party components:

```css
.THIS .slds-modal__container { 
  width : 60% !important; max-width : 80% !important; 
}
```

Still, I have just checked with Summer '19 and this component named "styleTest" does generate a style tag as you would expect:

```xml
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >     
  <h1>Aura Style Test</h1>
  <aura:html tag="style">
    .slds-modal__container { 
      width : 60% !important; max-width : 80% !important; 
    } 
  </aura:html>          
</aura:component>
```

This is the output once I add it to a page:

```html
<div data-component-id="styleTest" data-aura-rendered-by="348:0" class="flexipageComponent" data-aura-class="flexipageComponent">
  <h1 data-aura-rendered-by="352:0">Aura Style Test</h1>
  <style data-aura-rendered-by="354:0">
    .slds-modal__container { 
      width : 60% !important; max-width : 80% !important; 
    } 
  </style>
</div>
```

Therefore the change is really at the CSS level, or with the quickAction components.

Overriding global SLDS using your trick is clever, but it will depend on load order, changes in SLDS, or changes in the quickAction components (a conversion from Aura to LWC for example might/will happen).

Like any remedial CSS, the best I can suggest is:

- Short term: keep-up with the changes of each new release. Overriding SLDS of base components is not recommended, but you business needs might dictate so, and make it worth the investment.
- Mid/long term: Contact Salesforce to see if your issue can be solved/supported by the platform. I doubt you're the only person with that specific need and there might already be an elegant way to solve this problem.

I will contact other key players and post additional comments as answers comes up.

Comment: What I'm hearing at this point is that overriding/skinning SLDS classes isn’t really an API. We can't make any guarantees there. However, we'd love to have an API: tokens? CSS variables? CSS ::part and ::theme?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use this method to override the standard enhanced related list (the font size is just way to big on it in general, and generally defeats the purpose of having more then 4 columns)  I realize it's not supported and far from best practice but I don't see another way to do it without building my own enhanced related list component which would be madness. Worst case. SFDC changes class names.. drops the hammer and it falls back to bigger font sizes..

```
    <aura:html tag="style">
        <!--
        The desired effect here is to override the Standard LDS Enhanced Related list as its font size is way to big.
        (Inventory Request Line Items) This really isn't best practice at all and is not supported but is a
        necessary evil.
        -->
    .forceRelatedListPreviewAdvancedGrid .uiVirtualDataTable { font-size: .80rem; }
</aura:html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge in-component styles for aura are disabled when Locker Service is enabled, so it stopped working when Locker Service was enabled

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you use aura:html, mainly this need to be used when you want to bind some styling dynamically for example in your component file you bind an attribute this way :

```html
<aura:attribute name="backgroundColor" type="String" default="XXXXXXXX"/>
<aura:html tag="style">
  :root{
     --backgroundColor : {!v.backgroundColor}
   }
</aura:html>
<div class="custom-body">
   lorem ipsum...
</div>
```

then in the css file you use it this way :

```css
.THIS .custom-body{
     background : var(--backgroundColor);
}
```

there are other ways to use it as well, but this is the best utility i have seen. and it works still now.